# How is the Dirac delta $\delta (x^3)$ different from $\delta(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, dirac-delta

How is Dirac delta $\delta (x^3 )$ different from $\delta (x)$? It is my understanding that
$$
\delta [\psi]:=\langle\delta,\psi\rangle=\int_{\Omega}\delta(x)\psi(x)\,dx=
\begin{cases}
\psi(0) & \text{if $0\in \Omega$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
But $x^3=0$ iff $x=0$ so does this not imply,
$$\delta(x^3) = \delta(x) = 0$$
Apologies if I am completely misunderstanding the topic, I am very new to distributions.

Comment: Good question. The delta distribution with nonlinear arguments is a tricky concept. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56998/8157) of robjohn has been extremely useful to me in order to understand that.

Comment: Compare $\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\delta(x^3)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}u^{-2/3}f(u^{1/3})\delta(u)/3\,du$ with $\int_{\Bbb R}f(u)\delta(u)\,du$.

Comment: It appears to me that you are using conflicting notation. The "$\delta(x)$" appearing inside the integral is not the same as the "$\delta$" that is applied to $\psi$ on the left hand side.

Comment: Maybe too naive but øan't you substitute $y = x^3$ in $\int \delta(x^3) f(x) dx$ and see what happens?

Comment: I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481114/dirac-delta-function-deltafx-of-function-f-with-a-higher-order-zero

Comment: @pregunton I've updated the question to fit exactly what is written in my lecture handout

Comment: See also this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\psi$ be a test function, i.e. $\psi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} _{c}(\mathbb{R})$, then:
$$
\int \delta(x^3)\psi (x) dx = \int \delta(y) \psi (y^{\frac{1}{3}}) \frac{1}{3y^{\frac{2}{3}}} dy  
$$
Note that our new test function $\psi (y^{\frac{1}{3}}) \frac{1}{3y^{2/3}}$ is not smooth, hence we cannot define $\delta(x^3)$ as a distribution. In general, if $u$ is a distribution, then $u \circ g$ is a distribution as well if both $g$ and its inverse are smooth. In such a case: $\langle u \circ g, \psi \rangle := \langle u, \psi \circ g^{-1} |\text{det } dg^{-1}| \rangle$. Please note that the integration above is an abuse of notation.