# $x(2t) * \delta(5t+5)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How can i compute such convolution?
$$x(2t) * \delta(5t+5)$$
I know that $$x(t) * \delta(t) = x(t)$$
but how I tackle such one? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fundamental formula (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2481114)) is:

\begin{equation}
\delta(f(x))=\textstyle \sum_i\frac{\delta(x-a_i)}{\lvert f^\prime(a_i)\rvert}.
\end{equation}

where the $a_i$ are the roots of $f$. Have you seen it ?

Here with $f(t)=5t+5$, you can use it to convert:

$$\delta(5t+5)=\frac15 \delta(t+1)=\frac15 \delta_{-1}(t)$$

Convolving with $\delta_a$ amounts to a shift of $a$ units. Once again, did you know this important result ?

Therefore, your final result is the translation of $x(2t)$ on the left of one unit followed by  multiplication by $\frac15$.

Said otherwise, the result is:

$$\frac15 x(2(t+1))$$

(Thanks to Lutz Lehmann who pointed an error...)

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann You are right! Thank you. Not the first time that even after having given attention I fall into the trap... I correct it...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{align}
&\int_\mathbb{R} x(2(t-s))\,\delta(5s+5)\,ds \\
&\stackrel{u=5s+5}{=}\frac15\int_\mathbb{R} x(2(t-\frac15(u-5)))\delta(u)\,du
\end{align}

Comment: what do you mean by $t$ ?